# How can I figure out how many characters are in a number?

Tags: c, string, while-loop, char, int

So the length of:

`int test1 = 1` is 1 character long

`int test2 = 37` is 2 characters long

`int test3 = 82342` is 5 characters long.

---

I can find the character length of these int's using:

`int character_len = floor(log10(abs(whatever_vairable_here))) + 1;`

---

I want to count `int i = 1;` all the way up to `n`, but in the example code, I just used `20`). Is there a way where I can figure out the total number of characters I will use without using the first while loop to determine the size I have to malloc. I'm trying to figure out how much space I should `malloc`

```
int total_characters_needed = 0;
int i = 1;
while (i <= 20) {
    total_characters_needed += floor(log10(abs(i))) + 1;`
    i++;
}

char *my_numbers_as_a_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * total_characters_needed);

i = 1;
while (i <= 20) {
    sprintf(my_numbers_as_a_string, "%d", i);
    i++;
}

printf("%s\n", my_numbers_as_a_string);
// Should print out:
// 1234567891011121314151617181920
//
// If the above is unread-able its basically
// 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Is your question “What is the sum of the number of digits in the decimal numerals for all integers from 0 to *n*?”

Comment: could you not take an upper bound for the total size ? You will allocate too much memory that way, but it's a lot easier.

Comment: Why does your question say you start with `int i = 0;` but your code starts with `i = 1`? Which is correct?

Comment: You need `(10 - 1) * 1 + (21 - 10) * 2 + 1` characters to fit all digits. `(10 - 1) * 1` for the range `1` to `9`, `(21 - 10) * 2` for the range `10` to `20`, and then `1` extra for the terminator. It shouldn't be to hard to find a pattern

Comment: You could use [`asprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) which is not ISO-C, but GNU-C

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think that's what I am asking. I just want to know how many characters are between 1 to n, if I counted from 1 all the way to n. I also fixed the `int = 0` typo.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yea I could, but I want to be efficient, plus I don't know what the max number will be.

Comment: @PaulShan : technically you want to be efficient with your memory usage, but that'll come at the cost of cpu usage (to pre-calculate the size). Also, if being efficient with memory usage is the goal, do you really need to have that entire string in memory ?

Comment: @PaulShan : an easy upper bound could be the amount of characters of the maximum value (ie. `2` characters for the value `20` in your example), multiplied by the amount of values (ie. also `20` in your example), giving you a 40 character upper bound, which is not too far off the actual length of 31.

Comment: One simple possibility: sprintf to a local array large enough for even the biggest number, count the number of characters in this array (using `strlen`), reserve that number of bytes + 1of memory with `malloc`, copy from the local array to the allocated memory (using `strcpy`)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Rather than use `strlen()` to count the characters, use the prior `sprintf()` return value.  Yet at least 2 answers below provide an efficient  total, possibly  faster than even 1 call of `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of digits that are written if you write out the numbers from 1 to n, use something like

```
unsigned long digits(unsigned long n) 
{ 
    unsigned long total = 0;  
    for (unsigned long i = 1; i <= n; i *= 10){
        total += (1 + n - i); 
    }
    return total;  
}
```

For example, `n` being `11` produces `1234567891011` which has 13 digits.

The algorithm suffers from a defect in that it can loop on a sufficiently large `n`, and the cutoff is contingent on the range of `unsigned long` on your platform. Constraining `n` to be no larger than `ULONG_MAX / 10 - 1` would be sufficient.

Comment: Better, yet still infinite loop with `digits(MAX)`.

Comment: @chux. On your second point, oops. On your first one, needs a bit of thought. I'll have a think when I'm on the choo choo on my way home, unless you have something up your sleeve in which case ping me and I'll wiki the answer.

Comment: 1) To prevent infinite loop, can't use `i_same_type_n <= n`. 2) Since the range of `digits(x)` is wider than domain `x`, we are left with OF possibilities staying with one type. When some type exists much wider than `int/unsigned`, code could use wider types. e.g. `digits(unsigned n) ... uintmax_t total, i`. Since OP talks of allocation, `size_t` is the widest type _needed_.  The simplicity of this code is sweet even if some corners are cracked.

Comment: @chux: Good points made indeed. I'm thinking in terms of a closed-form approximation for the highest possible value of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a puzzle question. You want to store the sequence of numbers from 1 to some number **x** in string, so need the total of all the characters.
For example, let x=77867. So x is a 5 character long number. This can be found out using the loop as given by **user10334659**.

The first thing to notice is that the numbers from 1 to upto 4 digits are basically filled and do not depend on value of **x**. So we can first calculate the number of characters for these numbers.

1. 1-9 : single digits. #numbers = 9 .  => characters = 9 x 1
2. 10-99 : 2 char.      #numbers = 90.  => characters = 90 x 2
3. 100-999 : 3 char.    # numbers = 900. => characters = 900 x 3
4. 1000-9999 : 4 char.  # numbers = 9000. => characters = 9000 x 4

So the total characters for all numbers from 1 to maximum **y**-digit number is:

`9 ( 10^0 x 1  +  10^1 x 2 + ... + 10^(y-1) x y )`

Now we just need to count the total numbers from `10^(y)` to **x**(which is a (y+1)- digit number). For our case, 10000 - 77867 : #numbers = 67688   => characters = 67688x5.

**Time Complexity**

Let the maximum number be n. Then **y+1** can be calculated in **O(log(n))** time. Finding the characters from 1 to **y**-digit number also takes **O(log(n))** time. Lastly, number of characters from 10^**y** to n was found in **O(1)** time.

So this algorithm can find the total number of characters in **O(log(n))**  time as opposed to the naive O(n) time loop.

Comment: Sorry, I stole your thunder and wrote out the algorithm instead. Your answer + my answer = perfect answer. Have an upvote!

Comment: nice timing :) I had a feeling that I spent too much time formatting the answer. A code would be much faster :D

Answer (score 2):

The following code calculates the total number of digits in the decimal numerals for all integers from 1 to `n`:

```
int Digits = 0;
int LeadingZeros = 0;
for (int t = n; 0 < t; t /= 10)
{
    ++Digits;
    LeadingZeros = 10*LeadingZeros + 1;
}

int TotalDigits = Digits * (n+1) - LeadingZeros;
```

Reasoning: The loop calculates the number of digits in `n`, putting this number in `Digits`. If we wrote all integers from 0 to `n` as decimal numerals with `Digits` digits (using leading zeros, such as “003”), that would use `Digits * (n+1)` digits. From that, we want to subtract the number of leading zeros. (For zero, we want to subtract all of its zeros, so it has no net effect on our count.)

For `n` from 1 to 9, there is only one “0” to subtract, the one for 0. For `n` from 10 to 99, we want to subtract the 9 leading zeros in “01” to “09”, as well as the two zeros in “00”. Thus, for 10 to 99, we subtract the same one leading zero as for `n` in 1 to 9 but also ten more leading zeros. Similarly, for `n` from 100 to 999, we subtract those leading zeros plus 100 more—one more for each number from 0 to 99. Ultimately, the number of LeadingZeros is a number 111…111 with the same number of digits as `n`. We can see the loop calculates this in `LeadingZeros`, and so the total number of digits used is `Digits * (n+1) - LeadingZeros`.

When preparing a buffer for these digits, one more character should be included for a terminating null. Additionally, `sprintf(my_numbers_as_a_string, "%d", i);` will write the new number to the start of `my_numbers_as_a_string`. To concatenate new numbers, provision should be made for writing to the end of the previous numbers.

Comment: Yup, upped. Out of interest, why did you go for `/=10` rather than the multiplication?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Mostly just because `/10` was in my head first, but also `*10` has a risk of overflowing. On the other hand, `Digits * (n+1)` can also overflow before `- LeadingDigits` reduces it. So, in either case, an ideal solution requires a bit more tinkering. Although `*10` is going to overflow only long after the total number of digits overflows anyway. But at least `/10` stops before overflowing the later calculation, whereas `*10` could loop forever.

Comment: 1) Curious, why `0 < t` vs. `t > 0`?  The later, IMO, is clearer. 2) `Digits * (n+1) - LeadingZeros` can simply use wider math - perhaps `n+1ull`, when available, to prevent overflow.  3) Good and efficient code answer.  O(ln(n)).

Comment: @chux: I adopted a practice of always using `<` or `<=` in the absence of good reason to do it the other way. It is not a big deal; it is just a consistent pattern that helps me keep complicated compound conditions and loops untangled. I also prefer half-open intervals such as [0, n), which also means `i < n` is preferred to `i <= n-1`. Half-open intervals have some nice properties, such as [0, 2n) is a doubling of [0, n), while [0, 2n] is not a doubling of [0, n].

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes, that's very refined indeed. In C++, "<" is, in a sense, more fundamental than the other relational operators. The C++ standard library uses solely "<" to define ordering. And of course all the other relational operators can be defined in terms of "<" and the logical operators.

Answer (score 1):

Just print the number to a string, then count the string length? Or is that too simple?

```
int numdigits(int n)
{
    char buf[64];
    return(sprintf(buf,"%d",n));
}
```